# Binding Date and Time to a single Date model in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a requirement to allow a user to set a date & time for the start and end of a date range. Since input type datetime-local is currently unsupported in firefox and IE I can't use it. So I was hoping to share a single date model across a date and time input.

Like so:

```js
  angular.module('date.deleter', [])
    .controller('DateDeleteController', function($scope) {
      //force display to be a bit more human-readable
      var loadedAt = new Date(new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19));
      $scope.data = {
        theDate: loadedAt,
        minDate: loadedAt
      };
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.6" data-semver="1.4.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="date.deleter" ng-form="dateDeletingForm">
  <div ng-controller="DateDeleteController">
    <h1>Change Something And Watch Date Dissappear o_O</h1>
    <input type="date" id="theDate" name="theDate" ng-model="data.theDate" min="{{data.minDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd">
    <input type="time" id="theStartTime" name="theStartTime" ng-model="data.theDate" min="{{data.minDate | date:'HH:mm:ss'}}" placeholder="HH:mm:ss">

    <h3>output the scope here</h3>
    <pre>{{data}}</pre>

</html>
```

In the snippet I set a single date object to be the model of a date *and* a time input. And then output the scope data object into a div so I can see what is happening. I also set the min of the inputs to be the date and time they load.

If you load the snippet then change the values you'll notice that at some settings not just is the input marked as invalid but the date object disappears from the scope entirely. Sometimes to be returned when you undo your change.

Is this expected behaviour? Am I trying to do something crazy in exposing a separate date & time input as a single datetime model?

Comment: I'm looking at this in Chrome 45.0.2454.85 m. What I see is that date and time controls don't enforce the `min` attribute setting when typing or using the spin buttons, and the `theDate` property disappears from the model when the `min` setting on the date input is violated. So the behavior is sort of logical, but also kind of awkward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for the benefit of people who may end up here via Google I was trying to do something crazy!

The [documentation for the time input](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D) says:

> Model must be a Date object. This binding will always output a Date object to the model of January 1, 1970, or local date new Date(1970, 0, 1, HH, mm, ss)

So if you change the time field then the date of the bound model *might* be set to 1/1/1970. I also noticed that the timezone was applying as well so sometimes setting 00:15 in the time field would actually set 23:15 the day before.

However, if the model is marked as invalid it disappears from the scope. I think that is very weird but I can live with it now I know.